# Assign orignal Image instead of taking UIImage in string

Tags: uiimage, xcode10

[image]

In swift 4 or even in previous version we can get the complete image though this code

```
ProfileImg.Image = marker.png
```

etc but In swift 4.2, we can only have

```
UIimage.init(named: "marker")
```

Is it a version mistake or removed by own.???

Answer (score 1):

From the [Xcode 10 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=xcode-10-beta-rn):

> - Code completion for Swift image literals was removed in Xcode 10. (38087260)

I imagine this was because the image literals were appearing in the completion list for *everything* and not just when the context involved UIImage, which was driving everybody crazy. Or maybe it's because the new editor can't accommodate the display of image literals.

The feature will either be restored in a future release or will be abandoned altogether. Time will tell!

Comment: Ahaan okay, but it was helpful i think so, maybe they will add again...

Answer (score 0):

When you started to write mar.. you ll see the picker that contains your image in the assets. You can pick from here directly.